# Link to homepage in breadcrumbs/logo in subfolder?

Tags: hyperlinks, breadcrumbs

We recently launched our company blog. We created a new design for it to distinguish it from our regular shop design and give a more "blog experience". The blog is located at http://www.inktweb.nl/blog/.

I think its UX rule #1 to link your logo to homepage of your website. Does this hold true for subfolder? When a person is browsing the blog and they click on the logo, do they expect to be linked to the homepage of the store? Or the homepage of the blog?

Image to demonstrate: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mU74N.jpg

I recently changed it to the homepage of the blog (`/blog/`) because I feel that's more "natural". Also, please have a look at the breadcrumbs on a post. It's currently styled as:

Inktweb.nl > Blog > **Post Title**

`Inktweb.nl` links to the homepage of the store and `Blog` to the blog index. I think this is the best way to do it. Opinions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logo should connect it to the main parent. The logo or the image used as the logo should take the user to the main launch page. So if you have 2 websites one for main company and one for blog, then i would suggest to have a logo which says that it is for blog and not the main company site. I user a practice of using small text next to the logo called blog. Clicking on this will send the user to the blog homepage which is intuitive now. Alternatively, I keep a prominent link on the header from where the user can directly open the main company website.

Comment: I like the idea of a new/alternate logo for the blog. I'm going to go with this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by ajayashish, your main logo should go to your main company page. Ideally, you should then have another, smaller link (or image) to take the user to the blog homepage from wherever they are in a post. You can look at how www.opentable.com does it once you drill down in their site. (Their logo always goes to the homepage, and then they have a home link to go to the home area of wherever the user is looking for a restaurant.)